# Dropdown List with a relationship table attribute [MVC .NET]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-relationship, entity-framework-migrations

Since English is not my native language, I'm very sorry for any mistake I will exihbit in the next senteces.

I created a database with products (produtos) and types of Products (Categoria)

My objective was to create a relationship (codefirst) in MVC from One to Many.
Where a type of product (Categoria) can have multiple Products (Produtos)

So I had created this:

```
namespace HardwareWarehouse.Models
{
    public class Produto
    {
        public Produto()
        {

        }
        [Key]
        public int IDProduto { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public double Preco { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public double Peso { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        public int Imagem { get; set; }

        public DateTime UltimaAtualizacao { get; set; }

        public int Stock { get; set; } 

        public int CategoriaID { get; set; }

        public virtual Produto Produtos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And for the Category/type of Product (Categoria), I created this..

```
namespace HardwareWarehouse.Models
{
    public class Categoria
    {
        public Categoria()
        {
            Produtos = new List<Produto>();
        }
        [Key]
        public int CategoriaID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So I think my relationship between both tables are fine so far.

Next, I had created a controller, and used a default view to store some data.
Which looks like this:

[image]

And this is my default view that shows that info..

```
@model IEnumerable<HardwareWarehouse.Models.Produto>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Preco)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Peso)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descricao)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Imagem)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UltimaAtualizacao)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Stock)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoriaID)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Preco)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Peso)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descricao)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Imagem)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UltimaAtualizacao)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Stock)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoriaID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.IDProduto }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.IDProduto }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.IDProduto })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The Millions dollar question is?
How do I make the view to show the Categoria.Nome instead of the CategoriaID number on that view?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi Pedro, you can also feel free to ask in portuguese stackoverflow. Anyway, I suggest you read about view models. Instead of using `Produto` and `Categoria` as models for your view, it would be better creating a view model (e.g `ProdutoViewModel`) which would hold all properties you need (including `NomeCategoria`). You'd need to use projections, which seems to be a common practice. Also, this allows you to decorate your view models with some *data annotations validations*, thus allowing you to avoid mixing with database entities. I hope I could help somehow.

Comment: So a ViewModel is essentially like a view.. in a database environment?
I still need to keep the Produto and Categoria, because I use it for CodeFirst, it is those models that creates the database through Entity Framework, so I guess I can't just get rid of it, right?

Cheers.
And thanks.. I'm new to this, (need to find a way to upvote you XD)

Comment: Yes, you can think of a ViewModel as a view in a database, joining related tables. Do some research about projection while working with EF, and how to use ViewModels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Alisson answer, ViewModels are used to send multiple models to the view
Here is the Link
[ViewModel in ASP.NET MVC](http://tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/how-to-use-viewmodel-in-asp-net-mvc-with-example)